# converting a string to a simple one character value in C language

Tags: c, string, char, bison

I'm writing a compiler with Flex and Bison using C langage and need to  convert a character string to a one simple character . which functions should i use ? i can't find it .
forexample :

```
-string to integer we use : int i = atoi(yytext);
-string to float we use :   float f = atof(yytext);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "convert a character string to a one simple character"?

Comment: for exemple the string of one character "c" will be one caracter 'c'.we use this approch when converting strings to integer like : "2021" will be 
int integer= atoi("2021"); // 2021

Comment: Strings in C are just arrays of characters (with a 0 at the end) and characters are small integers. If you're going to try to use flex and bison in C, you really need to understand the way C represents strings. Hopefully, you have some kind of C textbook handy.

Comment: Is the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66297158/1971013) what you need?

Comment: yes it solves the problem . thank you so much my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, a character string with one value is just a character string of `[0]` so why not just do something like...

```
char new_char = char_string[0];
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP was asking, with the _caveat_ that a `char` does not necessarily translate into an actual printable character; that depends on the encoding. For example, æ.